# MySQL row number for each group with group memory

Tags: java, mysql

I'm doing a running program in Java and MySQL. So the runners can have statistic of who is in first place after the races finish. Also runners races under a category. So also there are winner under every category. All the data are in separate tables in MySQL, and when the races end, a query must show table position general and by category, depending of how quick they finish.

I have those tables in MySQL:

```
events (id, name, isActive)
runners (id, name, sex)
category (id, name, isActive)
inscriptions (id, event_id, runner_id, category, number_assigned, isActive)
race (id, inscription_id, start, end)
```

And I have this query that give me the table position once the race is finished.

```
SELECT  category.`name` AS `CATEGORÍA`, inscriptions.number_assigned AS `NÚMERO`, runners.name AS `COMPETIDOR`, runners.sex AS `SEXO`, races.`start` AS `INICIO`, races.`end` AS `FIN`, SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(races.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(races.`start`)) AS `TIEMPO`
    FROM `events` 
        INNER JOIN `inscriptions` ON inscriptions.event_id = `events`.id 
        INNER JOIN `races` ON races.inscription_id = inscriptions.id 
        INNER JOIN `category` ON inscriptions.category = category.id 
        INNER JOIN `runners` ON inscriptions.runner_id = runners.id
    WHERE `events`.id = 1 
        AND inscriptions.isFinished = 0 
        AND `events`.isActive = 1 
        AND `inscriptions`.isActive = 1 
        AND `category`.isActive = 1 
        AND `runners`.isActive = 1
    ORDER BY races.`end` IS NULL, SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(races.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(races.`start`)) ASC;
```

The reason of this first query is because I need the information of the table position. I include "race.end IS NULL" in group clause because I need runners without end time (didn't finish the race) at the end of the table.

This give me some result like this:

[image]

OK. If I try to do the normal procedure of adding "row number" everything got a mess because, the query first assign number to the row, and then apply order clause in it.

```
SELECT 
    @r := @r+1 AS `POSICION`,
    `category`.`name` AS `CATEGORÍA`,
    `inscriptions`.`number_assigned` AS `NÚMERO`,
    `runner`.`name` AS `COMPETIDOR`,
    `runners`.`sex` AS `SEXO`,
    `races`.`start` AS `INICIO`,
    `races`.`end` AS `FIN`,
    SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`start`)) AS `TIEMPO`
  FROM
    (SELECT @r:=0)y, `events`
    INNER JOIN `inscriptions` ON (`inscriptions`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `races` ON (`races`.`inscription_id` = `inscriptions`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `category` ON (`inscriptions`.`category` = `category`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `runners` ON (`inscriptions`.`runner_id` = `runners`.`id`)
  WHERE
    `events`.`id` = 1 AND 
    `inscriptions`.`isFinished` = 0 AND 
    `events`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `inscriptions`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `category`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `runners`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `races`.`end` IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY 
    `races`.`end` IS NULL, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`start`)) ASC;
```

And mess is everywhere:

[image]

OK. After been a while in search I do a query to get my "table position", and then cross it with another one to put row number so far. Works fine.

Now the category problem.

When try to do the same thing with the category system, the query only count consecutive sequence of the number, there is no memory in the category like "10 rows back where another master at 4 position, so this need to be 5". For be more specific attach a code of what is wrong and what should be.

WRONG:

```
1   1   Especiales  Especiales  614 Alex Chancusi   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:32:16 00:19:23
2   1   Juvenil Juvenil 491 Anthony Recalde Carrillo    M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:35:34 00:22:41
3   1   Master  Master  610 Marco Almache   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:35:50 00:22:57
4   1   Senior  Senior  632 Cristian Rafael Caizapanta  M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:36:17 00:23:24
5   2   Senior  Senior  138 Dennys Morocho Guayanlema   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:37:00 00:24:07
6   1   Master  Master  591 Manuel Suntaxi  M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:37:35 00:24:42
7   1   Senior  Senior  508 Jhon Robles M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:38:44 00:25:51
8   2   Senior  Senior  536 Margaret Karic Zoroitich    F   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:38:53 00:26:00
9   3   Senior  Senior  538 Carlos Moreno   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:39:20 00:26:27
10  1   Master  Master  550 Luis Toaquiza   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:39:43 00:26:50
```

Is wrong because if you see at position 3, there is a "Master" with the first place, and then a position 6 another "Master" with the same position, and the same at 10 position.

GOOD:

```
1   1   Especiales  Especiales  614 Alex Chancusi   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:32:16 00:19:23
2   1   Juvenil Juvenil 491 Anthony Recalde Carrillo    M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:35:34 00:22:41
3   1   Master  Master  610 Marco Almache   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:35:50 00:22:57
4   1   Senior  Senior  632 Cristian Rafael Caizapanta  M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:36:17 00:23:24
5   2   Senior  Senior  138 Dennys Morocho Guayanlema   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:37:00 00:24:07
6   2   Master  Master  591 Manuel Suntaxi  M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:37:35 00:24:42
7   3   Senior  Senior  508 Jhon Robles M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:38:44 00:25:51
8   4   Senior  Senior  536 Margaret Karic Zoroitich    F   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:38:53 00:26:00
9   5   Senior  Senior  538 Carlos Moreno   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:39:20 00:26:27
10  3   Master  Master  550 Luis Toaquiza   M   2016-10-09 07:12:53 2016-10-09 07:39:43 00:26:50
```

And so on. Always there is different category name, so a category list is not a proper solution.

The final query used for this result is:

```
SELECT @posGeneral := CASE WHEN z.`FIN` IS NULL THEN 'Not finished yet' ELSE @posGeneral+1 END AS `POS GENERAL`, 
  @posCat := CASE WHEN z.`FIN` IS NULL THEN '-' ELSE CASE WHEN @cat = z.`CATEGORÍA` THEN @posCat + 1 ELSE 1 END END AS `POS CATEGORÍA`, 
  @cat := z.`CATEGORÍA` AS `CAT`,
  z.* FROM(
  SELECT 
    `category`.`name` AS `CATEGORÍA`,
    `inscriptions`.`number_assigned` AS `NÚMERO`,
    `runner`.`name` AS `COMPETIDOR`,
    `runners`.`sex` AS `SEXO`,
    `races`.`start` AS `INICIO`,
    `races`.`end` AS `FIN`,
    SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`start`)) AS `TIEMPO`
  FROM
    `events`
    INNER JOIN `inscriptions` ON (`inscriptions`.`event_id` = `events`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `races` ON (`races`.`inscription_id` = `inscriptions`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `category` ON (`inscriptions`.`category` = `category`.`id`)
    INNER JOIN `runners` ON (`inscriptions`.`runner_id` = `runners`.`id`)
  WHERE
    `events`.`id` = 1 AND 
    `inscriptions`.`isFinished` = 1 AND 
    `events`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `inscriptions`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `category`.`isActive` = 1 AND 
    `runners`.`isActive` = 1
  ORDER BY 
    `races`.`end` IS NULL, 
    SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`end`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`races`.`start`)) ASC
)z, (SELECT @posGeneral:=0, @posCat:=0)y;
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a ***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is a lot of superfluous information in that query that has nothing to do with your problem of row number vs order by.

Comment: What do you mean with "superfluous information"?

Comment: [superfluous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superfluous): *1) being more than is sufficient or required; excessive. 2) unnecessary or needless*. The very opposite of ***minimal***. As the article in my first comment says about [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): *The more code there is to go through, the less likely people can find your problem. Streamline your example [...]* I would enhance that to say: *the less likely people are to look at your question*.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just find how to do it...

It something related to how MySQL understand the query, and how process the query for results...

Jus play a little bit with the ORDER clause and add a new level into query z.*, y.* and x.*

z.* for the row number
y.* for the "category" position (order by category)
x.* the original query.

Thanks anyway.